# fix table width a table inside table in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is my html,

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>123123123123213213</td>
            <td>123123123123123123</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Here is my css,

```
td{
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9drBk/

I have a table inside a table and I would like to make the td's width equal each other, but the css isn't working.

Any solutions please?

Comment: Why are you nesting tables? Also, you can't have a `<table>` after a `<tr>`, any table content needs to be inside a `<td>` tag.

Comment: your semantic is incorrect....a `<table>` **must have** `tr`,`td` to have data....how can you nest a data inside a table without a `tr`????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g4VB2/)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>123123123123213213</td>
                    <td>123123123123123123</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response :)